# My code is not printing the executed code

Tags: python, math, exec

```py
print(exec("5 + 5"))
```

its not printing 10 but prints None instead. I'm sure exec basically executes a code.

Comment: `exec` returns `None`. See the documentation for [**`exec`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exec returns None. You should probably use the eval() in this case

Comment: Why do Python beginners alway come up with `eval`? Please read: [Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't learn early about eval neither, I just answered the question